# PayPal: Cannot create sandbox account, and REST API account

Tags: rest, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, express-checkout

I tried to build the [Paypal Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/). Last week all runs smoothly, I can create REST API app and the sandbox account as well.

But today, All the details is removed.
And there is this warning

> We’re sorry, but something went wrong while getting your credentials.
>   Please try again.

When I tried to create a new app/new sandbox account it says

> We're sorry, something went wrong during account creation. Please try
>   again.

---

After some googling and trying some of the solutions like "password is too weak", I realise that all the solutions are from years ago and all the screenshot is the old PayPal interface.

I would assume that this is related to the new PayPal.
PS: I am from **Australia** and have read the "Non-US developers should read our FAQ"

**Anyone know how should I create REST API App?**

Answer (score 1):

This is not the correct way to create the API, but this resolves my problem instantly.

I had the same problem. The "Sandbox developer account" dropdown box had no entries although I had set up accounts before - so I couldn't create an app. After some trial and error hacking I finally found a way to inject a valid option in the html select and successfully created the app in the end.

Here's how:

Log in to your developer.paypal.com profile and go to Sandbox - Accounts.

Just use Firebug in Firefox or Developer Tools in Chrome to examine the source: Check the source of your BUSINESS account and you will find a code line like this:

```
<a class="profile" target="/developer/accounts/detail/22971020450123198612">Profile</a>
```

Note the id (e.g. 22971020450123198612), the country code (e.g. GB) and the email address.

Now go to Dashboard - My Apps & Credentials and press "Create app"

Open Firebug/Dev. Tools and examine the "Sandbox developer account" dropdown box. Right-Click the empty select in the dom and choose "Edit as HTML". Enter an option tag with your formerly noted values, just like this:

```
<option value="2297102045097598612,email@domain.com">email@domain.com (US)</option>
```

Check that the option now appears in the dropdown box.

Enter a name in the "App name" field and press "Create app".

That's it. Hope I could help.

Comment: Hahaha! Fantastic! This is like cracking PayPal code. Thank you Jayni